# HTML Horizontal role bar

Tags: html, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a html grid and I want to put it inside a container that can be moved asside without moving the whole page, something like this:

[image]

Any idea of how I can do that?

Comment: put it in a `div` (of fixed size) with its' style set to `overflow: scroll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Three Steps:**

1. Apply a [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) to the container.
2. Prevent [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) from wrapping.
3. Make the [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) scroll horizontally.

```css
.scroll-horizontal {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-horizontal">
  This is some content that needs to be scrolled horizontally.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a CSS class, e.x. `.scroll-x` and i CSS file do:

```
.scroll-x {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Does it help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside a container. Preferably using a div element. Then you'll need to give the container a fixed width so that its width doesn't scale (necessary for a horizontal scroll bar).

Then apply:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

To your container to make all content overflowing the fixed width horizontally the scroll-able.